# WebStorm and Dart autocomplete

Tags: dart, webstorm

I have been trying to figure this out for a few hours now with no result. I am doing some tutorial in trying to learn Dart. For some reason, my IDE does not seem to autocomplete like the instructors do. Anybody has any idea if there is any settings I should turn on?

On the left, is the video and on the right is what I am getting. In this case, I am not getting any `@overide`...

[image]

Answer (score 3):

It's relatively new feature, make sure you use one of the latest Dart SDK 2.0.0-dev releases.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. For some reason I installed dart 1 rather than dart 2 dev. I just did an updated and it works. Best regards and thank you 
  .https://www.dartlang.org/tools/sdk#install-using-a-setup-wizard

Answer (score 0):

Also don't forget to add the Dart support for your project because the language is not automatically selected :

> In Settings, go to Languages & Framwework, select Dart and verify the
>   Dart SDK path is correct.